# How to host Google fonts in WordPress theme locally?

Tags: fonts

I'm using a theme for my WordPress which uses 'Raleway' and it requests (13 requests in gtmetrix waterfall) it from Google fonts API. I want to keep using the font. However, I'm trying to reduce the number of requests and the size of my page. Can I include/integrate the fonts on my website so the browser won't have to execute any external requests?
many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download CSS with info about embedded fonts from Googleapis.com. Example link:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700&display=swap
```

Save the file right into your child theme directory so it’s now:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/theme-child/fonts.css
```

When you open this `fonts.css` file, there is content which looks like this:

```
/* latin-ext */
 @font-face {
   font-family: 'Montserrat';
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 400;
   font-display: swap;
   src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v15/JTUSjIg1_i6t8kCHKm459Wdhyzbi.woff2) format('woff2');
   unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
 }
...
```

Save font from `url` in newly created folder `fonts` in your child theme and replace path in `fonts.css` so it’s:

```
src: url(wp-content/themes/theme-child/fonts/JTUSjIg1_i6t8kCHKm459Wdhyzbi.woff2) format('woff2');
```

In my case, there were 60+ fonts to download. Therefore, I wrote simple PHP Downloader which I will be glad to open-source if somebody asks.

Add `fonts.css` to your child theme

```
/**
 * Add local fonts 
 */
 function jasom_add_local_fonts() {
 wp_enqueue_style( 'local-fonts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/fonts.css', array(), filemtime( dirname( FILE ) . '/fonts.css' ) ); 
 }
 add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'jasom_add_local_fonts' );
```

Flush all caches and check the source code for the presence of the following line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="local-fonts-css" href="https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/theme-child/fonts.css?ver=1607598699" type="text/css" media="all">
```

How to deregister existing Google Fonts out of your theme and more in the [source](https://www.jasom.net/host-google-fonts-locally-in-wordpress-theme/).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a child theme:
https://www.cssigniter.com/add-custom-fonts-wordpress-website-using-child-theme
I recommend that you test website load speed before and after the change, to make sure there's no negative effect.
It is recommended to use a CDN such as Google's.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Convert 'Raleway' font to web font using [Transfonter](https://transfonter.org/).
2. Download and upload the converted web font to WordPress via FTP or
   cpanel, ideally in the **wp-content/uploads** folder.
3. Now,it's time for adding custom font to css. You will have to change
   the default URLs in stylesheet.css. For instance, your default URLs
   in stylesheet.css looks like this:

   ```
   src: url('Raleway-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
   url('Raleway-Bold.woff') format('woff');
   ```

   You have to change them in the following way:

   ```
   src: url('t9w8m8j8.stackpathcdn.com/http://yourwebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/fonts/Raleway-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('t9w8m8j8.stackpathcdn.com/http://yourwebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/fonts/Raleway-Regular.woff') format('woff');
   ```
4. Finally test the Raleway font in a test page to check whether it is
   working or not.

You will find more information about these steps [here](https://onlinemediamasters.com/load-google-fonts-locally-wordpress/).